# definable set with parameters in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm facing some difficulties in understanding the relation between definable set with parameters and without parameters.

Roughly speaking, a definable set with parameters allows us to add parameters in the sentence determining the definable set.
That is $A\subset S\iff S\models\varphi(a,p)$ where $p$ is a parameter in $S$.

$\mathbb{N}$ is obviously not definable without parameters in $(\mathbb{Z},+)$. (Use the automorphism $x\mapsto -x$.)

My question is:

> Is $\mathbb{N}$ definable with parameters in $(\mathbb{Z},+)$?

I guess that the answer is negative but I have no idea of the proof.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are right to find this harder! Certainly automorphisms will not help anymore, since after fixing a single nonzero parameter (say, $1$) the structure $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ becomes rigid. At a glance I believe it actually takes some work to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is not definable with parameters in $(\mathbb{Z},+)$; if you haven't seen quantifier elimination or EF-games before, I would recommend steering clear of this problem for now (at least unless I'm having a silly moment).

Comment: Thank you for the guide!